# Select2 multi select not working

Tags: jquery-select2

Hi i used select2 (https://select2.github.io/) in my site and it's not working there. on click classes etc changed like example one but it didn't shows the select box options and there is no error in console. 
I am using multi select option of it.

Here is code:

```
<select name="xo_pages_show_name[]" class="spages" multiple="true">
<option value="4">Optin Demo</option>
<option value="2">Sample Page</option>
</select>
```

Here is jquery code in custom file and included in footer.

```
    $(".spages").select2({
     placeholder: "Select Pages"
});
```

Here is the frontend screenshot: http://i.prntscr.com/0d079920de3b4e3081a153b45cb9753a.png
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

No it was just problem with z-index.
Main container z-index was more than inner one. so it was not showing